# Extender nova classe CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Preciso construir uma classe onde eu faço a extensão da CI_Controller, para que eu não precise ficar "repetindo" funções que são usadas em todo o sistema... Por exemplo: Tenho um model de clientes, e outro de funcionários, ambas usam uma função chamada getById(), gostaria de não precisar repetir a função e deixá-las sempre dentro de um controller principal... Para ficar melhor organizado.

Comment: `getById()` fica no model ou no controller? esse método vai ter alguma implementação padrão?

Comment: Ele fica em todos os models do sistema, mas como ele é um padrão, eu quero deixar ele em um controller só, e chamo quando eu preciso... assim com as demais funções que eu tenho

Comment: @rray Gostaria que eu tivesse um arquivo onde eu concentrasse todas as funções que se fazem necessárias no sistema, que são padrão, sem eu precisar copiar e colar a função em cada model. Conseguiu entender?

Comment: Dependedo do caso vc pode criar uma library para isso, ou fazer o seu model implementar uma `interface` crud, que teria os métodos, save(), listaAll(), find(), delete() etc.

Comment: Sim, justamente essa minha idéia... ter uma a parte, para que eu chame quando preciso usar.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você faz isso no seu arquivo de configuração do Codeigniter:

```
// exemplo com o seu nome no stackoverlow
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'BILL_';
```

Depois você cria o arquivo `Bill_Controller.php` dentro da pasta `application/core`.

E o declara assim:

```
class BILL_Controller exends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function getById()
    {
      // Retorne algo aqui
    }
}
```

Em seguida, no seus controller você estende `BILL_Controller` ao invés de `CI_Controller`.

```
class Page_Controller extends BILL_Controller
{
    public function minha_acao()
    {
         $this->getById();
    }
}
```